# how to set ssl-mode in mysql library on nodejs ( in other platforms is called tls=skip-verify)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql  to connect to a db
(also tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2)

I need to be able to set ssl-mode like described here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connection-options.html#option_general_ssl-mode

is this possible ?

in other platforms is called tls=skip-verify

I tried already with rejectUnauthorize: false but didnt work

Comment: From the documentation you shared: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#connection-flags just use it on the flags: `-SSL` or `SSL` to enable it

Comment: @JorgeCampos Preceding a flag with `-` is to disable an enabled-by-default flag